# How Soyuz spacecraft still in service, even though one of it module displayed at museum?

Tags: spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft

How Soyuz spacecraft still in service, even though one of it module displayed at museum?

> One of the soyuz module is displayed clearly at museum.
>   [image: Soyuz T-10 Module displayed at Musuem]
>
> Info-box of Soyuz Spacecraft still showing in service. 
>   [image: Info-box of Soyuz Spacecraft still showing in service.]

Comment: I'm guessing it's either a prototype or a capsule used on a historic mission. Or similar to [one](http://www.space.com/13315-soyuz-capsule-intrepid-museum-space-tourist-greg-olsen.html) [of](http://www.museumofflight.org/news/soyuz-module-arrives-simonyi-space-gallery) [these](http://www.seattlepi.com/business/boeing/article/Soyuz-space-capsule-lands-at-Museum-of-Flight-2374765.php).

Comment: Also, it is the ONLY crewed spacecraft today! Chinese Shenzhou is a Soyuz copy. If you want, you could add the Soyuz rocket too, essentially the same which launched Sputnik I. Space flight today is a strange mixture of ancient and the future, like in some science fantasy fiction.

Comment: The Soyuz has been redesigned and updated a number of times. It is currently in its 4th generation. It has been a very successful design since the beginning, so no drastic changes have ever been made.

Comment: It's baffling why do you need an additional, nearly identical question regarding this when it was [already answered by Hobbes](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/6380/49) in [your previous question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/6378/49) hours before you posted this one. We can only reiterate in so many ways that Soyuz spacecraft isn't a single spacecraft and they don't reuse them. Please note that in English, "spacecraft" is a plural noun when not preceded by a determiner like "the", "a", and so on.

Comment: I agree with @TildalWave. Both of Hobbes' answers are good, but they both come down to the same thing - and still answer both questions.

Answer (score 5):

Soyuz spacecraft are not reused. So at the end of the mission, the descent capsule is no longer useful. The Russians have decided not to try reusing them, they just build a new descent capsule for each mission.
There have been hundreds of Soyuz missions, so there are hundreds of capsules going spare. Some of these end up in museums.

The Soyuz system is still in use. The capsule has been updated a few times, the current version is the TMA capsule. In 2014, there were [4 manned Soyuz launches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_R-7_launches_%282010%E2%80%9314%29).

So there is no contradiction between one capsule at a museum and the Soyuz still being listed as "in service".

Comment: then why still showing in service?

Comment: Because there are *other* Soyuz capsules that are being used.

Comment: @johnson316: I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Exactly. Just as there's no contradiction between all kinds of aircraft and cars and trains and who-knows-what-else being on display in museums while other examples of the same object are in everyday use.